# Multiple selection drag and drop in primeng Tree

Tags: angular, tree, treeview, primeng

Any suggestion for PrimeNg multi selection Drag and Drop. I have two trees, I'm dragging records from Tree A and dropping it in Tree B. I want to choose multiple records in Tree A and have to drop it at once in Tree B. By pressing ctrl I'm able to choose multiple records in Tree A but able to drag and drop only one record at time.

Is there any possible way where I can choose multiple records in Tree A and drop the same in Tree B at the same time.

```
<p-tree [value]="SenderFiles" [filter]="true" draggableNodes="true"
selectionMode={{SenderSelectionmode}} [(selection)]="senderNode"
(onFilter)="modifyNodeFilter($event)" 
(onNodeSelect)="senderNodeSelect($event)"
(onNodeUnselect)="senderNodeSelect($event)">


<p-tree [value]="ReceiverFiles" [filter]="true" droppableNodes="true"
selectionMode={{SenderSelectionmode}} [(selection)]="ReceiverNode"
(onNodeDrop)="onDrop($event)" [validateDrop]="true" 
(onFilter)="modifyNodeFilter($event)"
(onNodeSelect)="receiverNodeSelect()" 
(onNodeUnselect)="receiverNodeSelect()">
```

Comment: Didn't get a clue the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711205/multi-select-drag-and-drop-in-primeng) time you posted this? What code have you written to make this a reality?

Comment: It is an Angular Code. I'm trying to implement drag and drop feature in two trees  i.e.(From A->B). I'm selecting multiple records in tree A by pressing metakey (ctrl), on drag and drop event it allows only one record to get moved to tree B.

Comment: Don't tell us about the code in the comments. Show your code in the post.

Comment: Thanks for the response but could have asked it without closing the question. I will post back the question again when it allows after 90 mins. I have also edited the same question with code